# How to move a site collection to root path-based site collection in New SharePoint 2013 Farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, sharepoint-on-prem, backup

how to move a site collection to root path-based site collection in SharePoint.
I restored a content database in an SP2013 Farm from another SharePoint 2013 farm,  where this database is a site collection under a web application.

In New SP2013 Farm I want to restore this as root site collection how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand, you already restored the content database in destination farm.

- I will get the backup of the Site collection from Central Admin Using ["Recover data from an unattached content database."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/restore-content-from-an-unattached-content-database)
- Now i will use the .bak file and restore it using Backup-SpSite on the desired location.

Comment: Hi i was taken backup of site collection from production farm and restored using powershell in staging , but that sitecollection is not root site collection prod farm

Comment: after i restore i can not acess sitsettings and site content pages and applicaton not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the followings:

1. Save the site collection as a template with content and download the wsp file,
   then create a root site collection in the new farm using custom
   template.
2. After that, open the root site collection and upload the wsp file
   into solution gallery and activate it.
3. Go back to http://server/_layouts/15/templatepick.aspx, select the updated template and click OK.